# Querying Youtube for Embeddable Videos via the youtube_it Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, rubygems, youtube-api

I cannot find this documented anywhere and after looking over Google's api docs for YouTube ( http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos ) I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Basically i would like to query youtube in a way that the videos returned are only embeddable vids.

Currently i have something like this:

```
yt_client.videos_by(:query => "techno viking")
```

That search works great but will return all matching videos, even the ones that do not allow embedding.

Any ideas?  I'd love to have YouTube do the sorting instead of me filtering the search results with ruby. :)

Comment: Found the solution!  `yt_client.videos_by(:query => "techno viking", :format => 5)`.  From the doc page i linked above(and missed):  "Developers commonly add &format=5 to their queries to restrict results to videos that can be embedded on their sites."

Comment: Not really related to your question and answer, but do you know if youtube_it gem lets you get number of likes and dislikes on a video?

Comment: garbage collection, it can: https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/blob/master/lib/youtube_it/model/rating.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here with content from my last comment:

`yt_client.videos_by(:query => "techno viking", :format => 5)`

From the doc page http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos:

"Developers commonly add &format=5 to their queries to restrict results to videos that can be embedded on their sites."

Answer (score 0):

The format param wasn't working for me, but I found an "only_embeddable" option which does the trick:

```
yt_client.videos_by(query: "techno viking", only_embeddable: true)
```